# Remove an uploaded file

Tags: 7, forms, files

I am working with files in a Drupal module. I added this form:

```
$form['Background_image'] = [
  '#type'               => 'managed_file',
  '#title'              => t('Image'),
  '#progress_message'   => t('Please wait...'),
  '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
  '#description'        => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
  '#required'           => TRUE,
  '#upload_validators'  => ['file_validate_extensions' => ['jpeg jpg png gif']],
  '#upload_location'    => 'public://backgroundimage/',
  '#default_value'      => $this->options['Background_image'],
];
```

The file is added properly. Once the file is uploaded a remove button appears allowing to remove the file and upload a new one. The problem is that this button is not working. How can I remove an uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have uploaded a file you must be having file object so use [file_delete(stdClass $file, $force = FALSE)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_delete/7) to delete the file.

Comment: Normally that have to be done by the file module no?

Comment: yes on cron run it happens, but isn't this you aksed for?

Comment: yes but though once the button remove appears it have to work without adding a extra code, like once the form managed_file is created ,the function upload and remove are called automaticly once the user click  the button..